# Displaying posts by specific user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Here I have some code:

```
def show
    @post = Post.find()
  end
end
```

the user model has has_many :posts and the post model has belongs_to :user. Now how can I make the show action only display posts by the user logged in. User logged in is "current_user"?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
def show
  @post = Post.where(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

But there is glitch with the variable, you should rename `@post` to `@posts` since this will be an array of several Posts (if so, don't forget to change the variable in your view too!).

Comment: You should accept the answer if it fits your question @mangotango2005

Answer (score 0):

```
def show
    @posts = current_user.posts
end
```