# DIsplaying posts only created by specific user on his own dashboard

Tags: php, mysql

[Displaying posts by specific user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528885/displaying-posts-by-specific-user) this i saw is for ruby on rails and it couldn't help me..

I have two tables, users and posts.
If a user posts anything, it displays on his dashboard which works fine for now. But what i need is for the user to view only his posts.

Please help...

Below is my code:

server.php

```
<?php
    // connect to database
    require_once 'database.php';
    // initialize variables
        $note = "";
        $id = 0;
        $edit_state = false;


    // if save button is clicked
    if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $note = addslashes($_POST['note']);
        $created_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    // basic first name validation
    if (empty($note)) {
        $error = true;
        $noteError = "Field cannot be empty.";
    }else {
        // insert records if no error
        $query = "INSERT INTO posts (note, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('$note', '$created_at', NOW())";
        mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Saved";
        header('location: ../home.php'); // redirect to home page after inserting
    }
}
?>
```

and this is home.php where results are displayed

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once 'config/database.php';
  include 'config/server.php';

    // if session is not set this will redirect to login page
    if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    // select loggedin users detail
    $res=mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
?>
 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="wrap-status100">
        <form method="post" class="login100-form validate-form" action="config/server.php" autocomplete="off">
          <span class="login100-form-title p-b-26">
          <?php if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])): ?>
          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $_SESSION['msg']; unset($_SESSION['msg']); ?>">
          <span class="glyphicon glypicon-info-sign"></span>
          </div>
          </div>          
          <?php endif ?>
            What's up <?php echo $userRow['fname']; ?>?
          </span>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
            <textarea name="note" class="input100" value="<?php echo $note; ?>"></textarea>
            <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Write note here."></span>
          </div>
          <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
            <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
              <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                <?php if ($edit_state == false): ?>
              <button name="save" class="login100-form-btn">
                Save
              </button>
      <?php else: ?>
              <button name="update" class="login100-form-btn">
                Update
              </button>
    <?php endif ?> 
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </form>   

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])): ?>
    <div class="msg">
      <?php
        echo $_SESSION['msg'];
        unset($_SESSION['msg']);
      ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif ?>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Note</th>
        <th>created</th>
        <th>Updated</th>
        <th colspan="2">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['note']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['created_at']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['updated_at']; ?></td>
          <td><a class="edit_btn" href="home.php?update=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Update</a>
          </td>
        <td>
          <a class="del_btn" href="config/server.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am thinking indexing both tables using those keys or so... if i am on track, how do i do that?

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had to go through my codes again. I didn't create session in the server.php file I.e the file that controls the post form submission

Answer (score 1):

You need to take one more column in posts table i.e user_id. You have to store the id of user who create the Post.

While fetching the result, you can take logged in user's id. And create a query like

```
"Select * from posts where user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
```

by this you have get all the posts created by that particular user.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in this way:
First while adding a post you have to insert the user id of the user who is posting the post. Be sure to add a field named user_id in the posts table in db. PLease try this query:

```
$user_id=trim($_SESSION['user']);
$query = "INSERT INTO posts (note,user_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('$note', '".$user_id."' , '$created_at', NOW())";
```

Now in the dashboard of the user you need to fetch the posts based on the user_id and then loop the tr in the results array:

```
"Select * from posts where user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
```

Comment: Thanks but i have tried this and the user_id keeps displaying zero(0) in the database..

Comment: Post is getting created from the admin panel?

Comment: My posts table has columns id as Auto-incre, note, user_id, created, updated. Those 5 colums

Comment: @ Lalbhusan, post is created from the dashboard by the user and displays in the same dashboard of the user

Comment: Great so there should be the session id.While entering a post can you check the query by echoing it..

Comment: no i cannot, but the post enters the table perfectly but the user_id displays 0 no matter how many posts i iinsert

Comment: why you can't echo the query, any specific complexities...Whats your table structure of user table. Also can you confirm that $_SESSION['user'] has a value when logged in.

Comment: user table structure id,email,pass,fname,mdname,lname,created-at

Comment: Try this change $_SESSION['user'] -> $_SESSION['id']. Guess you are using the wrong column name..

Comment: Just did but it is now having redirect problem

Comment: Please make the changes in the site for the $_SESSION['id'] and then try to check that whether the issue gets fixed or not...

Comment: it didn't get fixed...but please let me clarify. Where did you get id and user. It seems not defined or am i getting it all wrong? there is no user in my tables, only id and this is in users table, then the user_id you asked me to create in the posts table

Comment: Yessss.. This worked perfectly. I had to go through my codes again. I didn't create session in the server.php file I.e the file that controls the post form submission. Once I did that, it submitted the post with the session id i.e user id. Thanks so much

Comment: Great that it worked. I had to leave so wasn't available in the intermediate time. PLease remmeber to upvote if it works so that it can be helpfull for others

Comment: I did but i was notified i have to get to a particular level